# How to describe and implement a function in TypeScript that includes specific properties?

Tags: typescript

I hope to design a message function that can be called directly and has overload capabilities. Then I also hope that there are other function calls under the message function, such as message.confirm(). This seems to be not easy to achieve in TypeScript, to write type descriptions, but it seems difficult to satisfy the types all at once when writing the implementation.

I tried to define a class, but when calling the class, it prompts that the new keyword must be used. I tried to directly define a function, but it cannot satisfy the properties of a function. This must be done step by step.

For example, let me define the following class,It will prompt that you must use new to call

```js
class message {
    message(msg: string): any
    message(msg: string, type: string): any
    message(msg: string, type?: string){

    }

    static confirm(){

    }
}

message("123")
```

I have another problem with using the following definition:

```js
type Message = {
    message(msg: string): any
    message(msg: string, type: string): any
    confirm(): any
}

const message: Message = function message (msg: string, type?: string)
    {
    }

message.confirm = function(){}
```

The final question is, how do I define and implement the message function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to treat a `Message` as a function, then it should have [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) instead of methods named `message()`:

```
type Message = {
  (msg: string): any // <-- call signature, not method
  (msg: string, type: string): any // <-- call signature, not method
  confirm(): any
}
```

Then your example code should start working as-is, due to the support for [property declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions):

```
const message: Message = function message(msg: string, type?: string) {
}

message.confirm = function () { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvAUFKAFALbwoBcU8wATgJYB2KAlBUvSHoSeZTQygBoooSBSp1GLKGw74AxgHt6AM1rUiBKTJwBfHDkX0qUIgmRoKcRKgxRlAV3pzgtJSbM3ipMX0ZCREAD8PhLM2Lr6ptZoAHSGqupQmA5OLm6a2FA6QA)

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to define and implement the message function as per your question.

```
type Message = {
  (msg: string): any;
  (msg: string, type: string): any;
  confirm(): any;
};

const message: Message = function (msg: string, type?: string) {
  if (type) {
    console.log(`Message: ${msg}, Type: ${type}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Message: ${msg}`);
  }
};

message.confirm = function () {
  console.log('Confirmation message');
};

// Example
message('Hello'); 
message('Hello', 'info'); 
message.confirm(); // Call confirm method
```